# How can I calculate atomic-resolved and orbital-resolved density of states using quantum espresso

Tags: density-of-states

I'm calculating the DOS and PDOS of Li2CuO2 using quantum espresso. How can I calculate the atomic-resolved and orbital-resolved density of states separately? I want to individually have DOS for Li Cu and O and orbital-DOS for the Cu atom.

I have used projwfc.x already and I have orbital-resolved and total DOS and I can't see the total DOS for the separate atoms.